# How do I get geodatabase automatically upated from edits in access database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase

I have an Access database that I have joined to a file geodatabase. There is a numeric field in the database that the symbology graduated colors is based on, ie: 0-39=red, 40-60 is orange, etc.

I am wondering what is the best way to update/edit the data within the access database (because these numeric values will change over time) in order to have it automatically update the attribute table/symbology colors in the file geodatabase. I just have Arcview 10 and Microsoft access.